Riemann sums for polynomials
When solving a programming problem, I needed to calculate Riemann sums for polynomials $\sum_{k=1}^tp(k)$, where $t$ is variable. In search for a solution, I found the Faulhaber's formula $\sum_{k=1}^nk^p=\frac{1}{p+1}\sum_{j=0}^p\binom{p+1}{j}B_jn^{p+1-j}$, which allowed me to solve the problem in $O(n^2)$. However, I feel uncomfortable knowing that the Riemann sum is similar to the Riemann integral, which I could calculate in $O(n)$ for polynomials.
My question is, is there a faster way to find Riemann sums for polynomials? I want to believe that this can be done at least in $O(n\log{n})$.

That's not a Riemann sum, it is just a sum.

Is the degree of the polynomial also  variable?

While ${x^k\mid k\in\mathbb N}$ is the usual basis for polynomials, there is an easier basis for this problem. Specifically, if you use the "falling factorial" functions: $$(x)p=x(x-1)\cdots (x-p+1)$$ then $$\sum{k=0}^n (x)p=\frac{(x){p+1}}{n+1}.$$ So if you write your polynomial in terms of this basis, you get an easier answer to this sort of problem.

You can also use the binomial polynomials $\binom xp$ and get for the sum $\binom x{p+1}.$ That's essentially an equivalent basis, just scaled. Falling factorials are slightly easier because they are monic polynomials.

@ThomasAndrews 1) From above, the Riemann sum with $\Delta{x}=1$. 2) It seems that you made a mistake in the sum formula for the falling factorial?

But every sum is a Riemann sum by that definition. There is no reason to think of this as a Riemann sum. You are correct, The equality should be $$\sum_{k=0}^n(k)_p=\frac{(n+1)_p}{p+1}$$

@ThomasAndrews I've read a little on this topic, but I still haven't figured out how to convert polynomials to factorial polynomials and back in less than $O(n^2)$. Could you reveal your idea?
